# Setting up pygame in virtualenv

Tags: python, pygame, virtualenv, sdl

I'm trying to setup pygame in my python virtualenv so that I can read controller data in using pygames Directinputs. I'm on windows 10 using the developer command line (basically bash mounted onto the windows system.) I have pygame installed, but I'm getting the error: pygame.error: No Available video device

```
ALSA lib confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4292:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver 
returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4292:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat 
returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1251:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4292:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned 
error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4771:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or 
directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Controller.py", line 36, in <module>
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.error: No available video device
```

I have tried using the command sudo apt-get build-dep python-pygame to get all the dependencies which seemed to download around 180 new files that I hoped would fix it, but of course didn't. I've also tried uninstalling and reinstalling pygame but that didn't do anything either. I think it is an SDL problem, or at least that is what google has yielded so far. I tried using

```
import os
os.environ["SDL_VIDEODRIVER"] = "directx"
```

and the other SDL_VIDEODRIVER flags, but none of them seem to change anything. Any suggestion as to how I can get the code to work? My code is simply the example program for pygames joystick object, so if you need reference [Here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/joystick.html) it is.

Comment: fixed for copy pastability

Comment: There are many ways to run bash on win10, but it sounds like you're running bash from ubuntu installed in the linux subsystem for windows. I'm not surprised if Pygame doesn't understand the window/graphics stack in that environment. You'll have better luck installing from dos.